# Is it a way to observe global variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, observer-pattern, key-value-observing

I want to add an observer to check changes of a global variable, but it not seems possible.

```
var selectedItem: NSManagedObject?

class LCCC: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // need to set up an "observer" that trigger selectedItemDidChange method, if selectedItem changed
    }

    func selectedItemDidChange {
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try using willSet ?

Comment: willSet is a property observer, I am looking for an observation method for global variables, in Objective-C it was not possible to use global variables, only static descriptor, the scope for it was the .m file, but in Swift it is possible to use global variables again

Comment: Correct, did you try observing the same way it was done in obj-c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most idiomatic way to do this in swift would be using property observers:

```
var test:NSString = "hi" {
    willSet {

    }
    didSet {

    }
}
```

(Although you need to provide an initializer)

Comment: I have added an other global variable where I store observer reference and from `willSet` I call `selectedItemDidChange` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(selectedItem, selector: Selector("selectedItemDidChange"), name: "selectedItemObserver", object: self)
```

Comment: I tryed like this, but does not work: `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("selectedItemDidChange"), name: "selectedItem", object: nil)`